# Node.js filling child object with data from parent object (inheritance using util.inherits)

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance, design-patterns

let's say that I've got a parent (let's say base) object, and a child object that's an extended version of base one.

I'll use sample code from  [metaduck.com](http://metaduck.com/08-module-pattern-inheritance.html). Here we have the parent:

```
function Animal() {

  var walked = false

  function walk() {
    console.log('walking...')
    walked = true
  }

  function hasBeenWalked() {
    return walked
  }

  return {
    walk: walk
  , hasBeenWalked: hasBeenWalked
  }
}
module.exports = Animal
```

and the child:

```
var Animal = require('./animall')

function Cat() {
  var cat = {}
  var walked = false

  cat.__proto__ = Animal()

  cat.pat = function pat() {
    console.log('being patted')
  }

  cat.lasagna = function lasagna() {
    console.log('Lasagna!')
    walked = true
  }

  return cat
}

module.exports = Cat
```

It works great if you don't have any parameter in constructors, but let's say that we've an `Animal(color,size)` and a `Cat(name)`.

Is there a simple way to get a `Cat('Garfield')` filled with data from already existing `Animal('orange','big')`? I would like to make some kind of factory from Animal that creates a lot of Cats with different names. How can I do that?

The only way I can think of is a method called for instance `makeCat(name)` in object `Animal(...)` that creates `new Cat(color,size,name)`

Comment: That's not a constructor, that's a factory. And you cannot use `util.inherits` with it.

Comment: Just use `function Cat(name) { …; cat.__proto__ = Animal('orange', 'big'); … }`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to restructure a bit.

```
function Animal( args ) {
  // this is your constructor
  // arguments can be used here
}

Animal.prototype.walk = function() {  }
Animal.prototype.etc_etc_etc

function Cat( args ) {
  Animal.call( this, additional, arguments )
}

utils.inherits( Cat, Animal )

Cat.prototype.pat = function() { }
```

The call to the `Animal` constructor is where you would pass additional arguments to the super class.

Alternatively, the stable version of node supports class syntax

```
class Animal {
  constructor( args ) {

  }
  walk() { }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
  constructor( args ) {  
    super( additional, arguments )
  }
  pat() { }
}
```

The major benefit of creating your "classes" like this is that you set up the prototype chain properly. With your current solution, where you tack on methods to `this` within the constructor, you'll create those methods for every object you create, 100 `cats` means 100 identical `pat` functions. Prototypal inheritance in JS means that `pat` should be on the prototype, where all 100 instances of `Cat` can use that one function (binding scope to themselves, you dont have to worry about this, the JS engine does it).

Comment: How can I create a Cat from Animal object with Animal's data included?

Comment: Both of these methods do that. i.e. `cat.walk()` will do its thing.

Comment: I know, but it's not the point of the question. Let's say that I've already created an Animal, but wanna convert the object to Cat and use Cat's methods on him

Comment: Oh I see. Yeah, sounds like you'd need a custom convert function, although JS is prototypal rather than classical so you can use an object as the prototype for another. I think you've pretty much got that, but extend the prototype (easiest just copy props onto prototype) rather than replace it.

Comment: Yeah, I had the same idea but thought that there's a prettier one.